# How to specify unknown type in static variable

Tags: generics, rust, types

I want to have a very generic top-level HashMap.

```rs
static mut cache: HashMap<std::hash::Hash + Eq, MyBox<_>> = HashMap::new();
```

MyBox is a smart pointer.

I get all these errors:

> the placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures for static variables

> only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
> **help**: consider creating a new trait with all of these as supertraits and using that trait here instead: `trait NewTrait: Hash + Eq {}`

> the trait `Eq` cannot be made into an object

And also a warning "trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated"

How can I create a `static mut` HashMap that allows any keys and any boxed values?

Comment: Doesn't the first error message indicate that it is impossible to use `_` inside the type of a static variable?

Comment: @kotatsuyaki yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire thing seems like a very dubious xy problem, mutable statics are frowned upon to start with. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

> How can I create a static mut HashMap that allows any keys and any boxed values?

You can't create a hashmap which allows "any key". As the last error message indicates, [`Eq` is not object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety), so you can't create a trait object anywhere near `Eq`, which means you can't create a "dyn any" key which is equatable.

By comparison the placeholder issue can be solved relatively easily, by making the values [`Box<dyn Any>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html), though what you'd do with that I can't tell you.

Comment: Very possible, I'm still struggling to think as a rustacean should. Thanks for the feedback. I want to make a caching smart pointer, so all `MyBox::new(thing)` return the same value if `thing` has been seen before.

Comment: I asked a question about the X of this question's XY problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74617570/3310334